# In C++, adding element to dynamic array is done by creating a new array. In languages like Python, does it do similar thing at the assembly level?

Tags: c++, arrays, assembly, programming-languages

I used many programming languages that had something like `.push()` or `.append()` to add an object to the end of a dynamic array. Now, I learnt some C++ and noticed that it does not support that, but I instead have to implement a function that manually does this, and this function creates a new temporary array that is one element longer, loops through the old array and copies each element, adds the new object, deletes the old array, and copies the temporary array to the old array. Does the languages I already worked with that allow functions like `.push()` do the same thing at the assembly level?

Comment: Side note: Avoid *new temporary array that is one element longer*. Instead allocate an array that is much larger, 50 to 100 percent larger, so you don't have to reallocate and copy as often. Wastes a bit of space, but most of the time memory is cheap.

Comment: ***that had something like .push() or .append() to add an object to the end of a dynamic array.  Now, I learnt some C++ and noticed that it does not support that, but I instead have to implement a function that manually does this,*** c++ has this with `std::vector<>` you are  learning more advanced concepts when manually allocating dynamic arrays yourself / creating your own lower functionality vector. After you learn how a vector works just use std::vector when you need a dynamic array.

Comment: @user4581301 @ drescherjm thanks both but I am really interested in how it is done at the assembly level. If I learnt a more advanced concept in C++ with the manual resize() function, but it actually teaches me something more fundamental like how it is done in assembly, that would be great. It seems irrational that C++ would "overcomplicate it" compared to other languages, so I assume they just hide it but do something similar under the hood, hence why I ask.

Comment: (My interest is really mainly at lowest level, transistors, and upwards, and last down comes high level languages, but I am not good enough to already know the answer to my question, hence why I ask. )

Comment: Understood. At the bottom end, everybody grabs a bunch of memory, and if it's not enough, they grab more. Copying might not be necessary, though because there is a lot of magic going on down in the hardware that might make the copying unnecessary. For example, say you ask for 128 bytes. The hardware may dole it out in 4k chunks. If the system is smart when you ask for 256 bytes you get the *exact same memory* so you don't actually have to copy anything. When you get to the point where more than 4K is needed, you don't get an 8K block, you get 2 4K blocks that, thanks to virtual memory...

Comment: ...look like they are side by side. The original memory still doesn't need to be copied because it's still in the same place. The smart system will take advantage of this.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, we also have constructs that do their own memory management: `std::vector<>` comes to mind. It is advisable to be used over plain arrays when appropriate. `std::vector<>` maintains a buffer and resizes + moves only when necessary (i.e., when the buffer is too small to hold the newly inserted element); then it expands usually to double or similarly.

In other languages, you also need to implement some kind of memory management. However, it's not trivial whether this kind of resizing is necessary: for most scripting languages are actually implemented in a lower-level language, very usually C/C++/C--. So it's possible that `std::vector<>` (or even `std::map<>`) is used in the background. However, at the end of the day, someone must implement resizing <sup>1</sup>, as memory is usually viewed as a one-dimensional array from which you allocate; you can't necessarily extend an allocation infinitely.

<sup>1</sup> Note: theoretically, on some architectures it'd be possible to delegate this to virtual memory management and use segment registers for pointers, index registers for offsets, and let paging associate segment:index to physical addresses; however, that's rarely used nowadays.

Comment: A good implementation should use OS support like [Linux `mremap`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html) to get more pages contiguous with the allocation when growing (potentially even moving the mapping to a new virtual address), not actually copying anything.  C++ `std::vector` can't easily take advantage of this because it's required to use `new`/`delete` which is an overly simplistic API that doesn't provide a reallocate, but `new` is overridable / replaceable so library implementations can't just do something equivalent *as-if* new and delete were being called.

Comment: (At least for large allocations `mremap` is appropriate.  For small allocations that aren't even a whole page, e.g. 4k, getting a larger allocation from the free list and copying can be more efficient than a system call, even if there isn't a block in the free list contiguous with the current position to just extend it.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes they do. For example python list (which are arrays, not lists) is doing exactly the same.

Note: You do not have to implement this yourself. That's what the STL is for in C++ and the relevant data structure for a dynamic array is `std::vector`. Except `std::vector` is smarter about growing the array, growing it by more than one element so not every push has to copy all the previous data. In fact it has ammortised cost of `O(1)` per push. If you know how much data you have it's still best to `reserve` the right amount of space from the start though.

Comment: Thanks that sounds very good. It tells me I learn something fundamental about how programs are compiled from learning C++ dynamic arrays. I have seen people recommend std::vector, and thanks for also recommending it, but my goal in "IT" is to understand the machine code level mostly. Learning a language like C++ is only second to it.